# How to do a dplyr inner_join col1 > col2

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

I am having difficulty with getting dplyr joins to work when I am not using the standard "col1" = "col2" join. Here are two examples of what I am experiencing.

Firstly:

```
library(dplyr)

tableA <- data.frame(col1= c("a","b","c","d"),
                     col2 = c(1,2,3,4))

inner_join(tableA, tableA, by = c("col1"!="col1")) %>% 
  select(col1, col2.x) %>% 
  arrange(col1, col2.x)
```

> Error: `by` must be a (named) character vector, list, or NULL for
>   natural joins (not recommended in production code), not logical

When I replicate this code but using sql I get the following:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

copy_to(con, tableA)

tbl(con, sql("select a.col1, b.col2
              from 
              tableA as a
              inner join 
              tableA as b
              on a.col1 <> b.col1")) %>% 
  arrange(col1, col2)
```

Results from sql query:

```
# Source:     SQL [?? x 2]
# Database:   sqlite 3.19.3 [:memory:]
# Ordered by: col1, col2
     col1  col2
     <chr> <dbl>
 1     a     2
 2     a     3
 3     a     4
 4     b     1
 5     b     3
 6     b     4
 7     c     1
 8     c     2
 9     c     4
10     d     1
# ... with more rows
```

Second part is similar to the last:

```
inner_join(tableA, tableA, by = c("col1" > "col1")) %>% 
   select(col1, col2.x) %>% 
   arrange(col1, col2.x)
```

> Error: `by` must be a (named) character vector, list, or NULL for
>   natural joins (not recommended in production code), not logical

Sql equivalent:

```
tbl(con, sql("select a.col1, b.col2
              from tableA as a
              inner join tableA as b
              on a.col1 > b.col1")) %>% 
   arrange(col1, col2)
```

Results from second sql query:

```
# Source:     SQL [?? x 2]
# Database:   sqlite 3.19.3 [:memory:]
# Ordered by: col1, col2
   col1  col2
  <chr> <dbl>
1     b     1
2     c     1
3     c     2
4     d     1
5     d     2
6     d     3
```

Does anyone know how to create these sql examples but using dplyr code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first case:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

expand(tableA, col1, col2) %>% 
  left_join(tableA, by = 'col1') %>% 
  filter(col2.x != col2.y) %>% 
  select(col1, col2 = col2.x)
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 2
     col1  col2
   <fctr> <dbl>
 1      a     2
 2      a     3
 3      a     4
 4      b     1
 5      b     3
 6      b     4
 7      c     1
 8      c     2
 9      c     4
10      d     1
11      d     2
12      d     3
```

For your second case:

```
expand(tableA, col1, col2) %>% 
  left_join(tableA, by = 'col1') %>% 
  filter(col2.x < col2.y) %>% 
  select(col1, col2 = col2.x)
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
    col1  col2
  <fctr> <dbl>
1      b     1
2      c     1
3      c     2
4      d     1
5      d     2
6      d     3
```

Comment: This will would work perfectly for on dataframes in R. What would suggest if the data frame is on a database and you are using dplyr to connect to the database. I will edit the main issue to highlight this.

Comment: @DyfanJones when asking additional question, it better to ask new one

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. The idea is to expand the data frame and then perform join to the original data frame. After that, use `fill` from `tidyr` to fill in `NA` to previous records. Finally, filter out records with the same values and `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tableB <- tableA %>%
  complete(col1, col2) %>%
  left_join(tableA %>% mutate(col3 = col2), by = c("col1", "col2")) %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  fill(col3, .direction = "up") %>%
  filter(col2 != col3, !is.na(col3)) %>%
  select(-col3) %>%
  ungroup()
tableB
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#    col1  col2
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1     b     1
# 2     c     1
# 3     c     2
# 4     d     1
# 5     d     2
# 6     d     3
```

**DATA**

```
tableA <- data.frame(col1= c("a","b","c","d"),
                     col2 = c(1,2,3,4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```